# What is the difference between nets and buses in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

As the title, who can tell me the difference between bus and net in Altium?

Comment: Buses are groups of nets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A net is one connection, or rather one node, of a circuit. Anything on that net is connected to everything else on that net. A bus is a variety of different nets that are grouped together to clean up schematics and make them easier to read. Instead of having individual wires tracing all over the schematic, you can use buses to group them together and they appear as one thick wire.

You can think of a net as a single wire, and a bus as a bunch of wires bundled together.

Comment: Buses do not matter for connectivity though, as far as I can remember. You have to label every net in a bus on both ends, so there is no electrical purpose to the bus graphic as such.

Comment: This is correct, buses are ONLY used to clean up schematics (organizational purposes). They have no electrical function.